# ASP.NET MVC Razor design table with rowspan

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-table

How can I merge cells in a table using rowspan inside a Razor view? I want to automatically merge date and link cells so I only have one of each for all data from a given day, instead of “Date” and “link” Cell in each row. I tried to solve it using conditions, but I either get an error (syntax problem I guess) or I get a different result than I wanted (example code down).

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var dayIncidentPair in Model.List)
                   {
                       <tr>
                           <td rowspan="@dayIncidentPair.Item3.Count()">Finded segment in @dayIncidentPair.Datetime.ToString("d")</td>
                           <td rowspan="@dayIncidentPair.Item3.Count()"><a href="~/path">Link here</a></td>
                           @{int i = 0; }
                           @foreach (var segmentInfo in dayIncidentPair.Item3)
                           {
                               if (i > 0)
                               {
                                   <text></tr>
                                   <tr></text>
                               }
                               <td>@segmentInfo.MValue1.Time.ToString("t")</td>
                               <td>@String.Format("{0:f1}", @segmentInfo. MValue1.Value)</td>
                               <td>@segmentInfo.MValue1.Type</td>
                               <td>@segmentInfo.MValue2.Time.ToString("t")</td>
                               <td>@String.Format("{0:f1}", @segmentInfo.MValue2.Value)</td>
                               <td>@segmentInfo.MValue2.Type</td>
                               i++;

                           }
                           </tr>
                   }

    </tbody>
```

I want something like this

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║    Date    ║    Link    ║ Time V1 ║ Value V1 ║ Type V1 ║ Time V2 ║ Value V2 ║ Type V2 ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 25.01.2017 ║    Link    ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
║            ║   to XXX   ║    9:10 ║     1.1  ║     A   ║    9:15 ║     5.3  ║     Q   ║
║            ║            ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
║            ╠            ╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║            ║            ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
║            ║            ║    9:30 ║     2.0  ║     B   ║   11:30 ║     4.1  ║     A   ║
║            ║            ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 26.01.2017 ║ Linkto XYX ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
║            ║            ║   11:50 ║     6.2  ║     A   ║   14:27 ║     5.3  ║     P   ║
║            ║            ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 27.01.2017 ║ Linkto XXY ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
║            ║            ║    8:03 ║     2.5  ║     Q   ║    9:47 ║     2.5  ║     A   ║
║            ║            ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
║            ╠            ╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║            ║            ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
║            ║            ║   13:21 ║     4.6  ║     A   ║   14:53 ║     4.3  ║     C   ║
║            ║            ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
║            ╠            ╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║            ║            ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
║            ║            ║   15:10 ║     7.4  ║     C   ║   15:45 ║     7.3  ║     B   ║
║            ║            ║         ║          ║         ║         ║          ║         ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848883/row-span-using-mvc5/42849042#42849042) for an example

Comment: I think I'd go with a nested table rather than using rowspan for this.

Comment: @nurdyguy Thanks for reply but in my humble opinion we are not at the beginning of the millennium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the Issue from a different angle and I found a solution. Apparently there was a problem with marking HTML tags through an IF condition.

The solution is therefore not to use use tag `<text>` but to use  `@:`

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var dayIncidentPair in Model.List)
                   {
                       <tr>
                           <td rowspan="@dayIncidentPair.Item3.Count()">Finded segment in @dayIncidentPair.Datetime.ToString("d")</td>
                           <td rowspan="@dayIncidentPair.Item3.Count()"><a href="~/path">Link here</a></td>
                           @{int i = 0; }
                           @foreach (var segmentInfo in dayIncidentPair.Item3)
                           {
                               if (i > 0)
                               {
                                   @:</tr><tr>
                               }
                               <td>@segmentInfo.MValue1.Time.ToString("t")</td>
                               <td>@String.Format("{0:f1}", @segmentInfo...
```